# Sorting data into appropriate key in an object

Tags: node.js, rpc, blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to loop & sort a large number of data ( the whole ethereum blockchain lol )

I'm trying to create a record of all transactions for every address.

Obviously this is a very intensive process and I'm not sure how to make it more efficient beyond what I have (which isn't that efficient)

It starts out quick but I'm thinking now it has slowed because of the lookup for the address in the `txs` object.

Any help opinions / help is greatly appreciated.

https://giphy.com/gifs/3o6fJ7KWqxESY9okk8

```
var txs = {};

var i = 0;
// Loop over blocks
(function loop () {
setTimeout(function () {
  // Get current block
  var block = web3.eth.getBlock(i, true, (error, block) => {
    // debugger;
    // Loop over transactions in block
    for(var j = 0; j < block.transactions.length; j++) {
      // debugger;
      if(txs[block.transactions[j].to]) {

        txs[block.transactions[j].to].transactions.push(block.transactions[j]);
      } else if (txs[block.transactions[j].to]) {
        txs[block.transactions[j].from].transactions.push(block.transactions[j]);
      } else {
        txs[block.transactions[j].to] = {
          transactions: [block.transactions[j]]
        }
        txs[block.transactions[j].from] = {
          transactions: [block.transactions[j]]
        }
      }
    }
  });
  i++
  if (i < highestBlock) {
    loop();
  }
 }, 50);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code has an error in it located at "else-if", it seems that you should use the `txs[block.transactions[j].from]` property instead of the `txs[block.transactions[j].to]`. If you simply want to accomplish a recursive pattern you could use the [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args) function or the [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args) method. If you use node.js v6+ you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of the object.

Comment: Thanks I missed that in the else if. It silent errored :P I'll look into that stuff thank you

Comment: That wasn't much more efficient.

Comment: In this example i'm just using ES6 but that shouldn't increase your performance but it should be easier to maintain. https://jsfiddle.net/o7xwg3p4/